# Derivative of $\|\cdot\|^2_1$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, normed-spaces

I have to find the partial derivative of the function $\frac{\partial}{\partial{X}}||X||_1^{2}$

I know that derivative of $||X||_1$ is $-1$ where $||X||_1 > 0$ and $-1$ where $||X||_1$ < 0 and not defined at $||X||_1 = 0$.

Thus using the chain rule can I write the derivative of $||X||_1^{2}$ as:

$-2||X||_1$ where $||X||_1 < 0$ and
$2||X||_1$ where $||X||_1 > 0$

Comment: The easiest way is to try on an example to see how it works. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you have
$$
f(x,y) = \|(x,y)\|_1^2 = \left(|x| + |y|\right)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + 2|xy|.
$$
Can you take the partials here and see what is happening? Can you generalize to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$?

Comment: @gt6989b for $xy > 0$, the derivative would be $(2(x+y))^2$ which can be generalized as $2||X||_1^2$ where $\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i > 0$. However, for $xy < 0$ it's -$(2(x-y))^2$ which I can't seem to generalize

Comment: Does not sound right to me -- doesn't the derivative get rid of the square power?

Comment: How can $\|X\|_1$ be $<0$ !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sign function
$${\rm sign}(z) = \begin{cases}
+1  &{\rm if\,\,}z\ge 0 \\
-1  &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
applied elementwise to the matrix $\,\,S = {\rm sign}(X)$.

Use this to write the norm. Then find its differential and gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= \|X\|_1 = S:X \cr
d\alpha &= S:dX \cr
d(\alpha^2) &= 2\alpha\,d\alpha = 2\alpha\, S:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\alpha^2}{\partial X} &= 2\alpha\, S = 2\|X\|_1\,\,{\rm sign}(X) \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the matrix inner product, i.e.
$$A:B={\rm Tr}(A^TB)=\sum_{i}\sum_{j}A_{ij}B_{ij}$$

The preceding assumes that the components of $S$ don't change, i.e. $\,dS_{ij}=0$.

In reality, there's a discontinuity at $X_{ij}=0$.